# "To whom" in pied-piped infinitive relative clauses

Tags: syntax, english, cases, relative-clauses, wh-words

In English wh raised from, or in situ in, a direct object or prepositional object, you can almost always use "who" at least as well as "whom",<sup>1</sup> and in some cases you can *only* use "who":

- Who/whom did you meet?
- Who/whom were you talking to?
- To who/whom were you talking?
- I asked her who/whom to talk to.
- I asked her who/?whom she met.
- I asked her who/whom she was talking to.
- What did you give to who/whom?
- You gave it to who/*whom?!
- I already told you about what to talk about to who/whom.
- I already told you about what to talk about, to who/whom.
- I already told you about what to talk about, and to who/whom.

But there seems to be at least one case where whom is actually required: when pied-piping a to-adjunct out of a relative clause, or at least an infinitive one:

- I already told you about the man to *who/whom to talk.

Is there any principled reason for this one construction to be different from all the others?

---

More specifically, is there any way to account for it in mainstream generative grammar?

As I understand it, all of the examples above are usually explained by the fact that "who" is marked with (abstract) accusative/ACC or oblique (depending on your favorite flavor of Case theory), but modern English allows realizing accusative "who" as either "who" or "whom", or similar. But then why does it *not* allow it in this one sentence?

---

Or, alternatively: In a construction grammar it's easy to account for: the pied-piped infinitive relative clause construction just overrides whatever is inherited from the parent construction(s), so that it requires "whom".

But such an unmotivated idiosyncrasy should eventually die away.<sup>2</sup> And "whom" has had a long time to do so, and all the other uses of whom are well on their way, but this construction seems to be stubbornly insisting on it without exception, even today. So, why?

My best guess—which seems like a pretty bad guess—is the very minor phonological infelicity of "to who to", which doesn't appear in any of the other examples.

---

<sub>1. At least by actual speakers of English—even in formal writing. Most prescriptive grammar writers claim it's incorrect, but then they also mandate hypercorrecting to "whom" even in instances that are clearly nominative, like the infamous "Whom shall I say is calling?" And of course most of them don't allow wh-raising without pied-piping in the first place, so half of these examples can't even arise for them.</sub>

<sub>2. Also, of course any CxG framework will leave room for a few nuts that just don't crack right, because languages don't have to be perfect. But that's a last resort fallback, not the default assumption.</sub>

Comment: I doubt it has to do with phonology, since I think it's much the same situation with things like "with who?(m) I...".

Comment: @sumelic Maybe you're right; maybe the general pattern is that pied-piped adjuncts take "whom" (which could just be a matter of pied-piping being a high-falutin' register?), and the few cases where you can pied-pipe "to who" are actually the idiosyncratic exceptions? I think I need to go gather some more examples…

Comment: I had thought of it as being a matter of the pied-piping construction being high-register and not really part of the synchronic naturally acquired "grammar" of English speakers. I don't know whether there are alternative analyses.

Comment: @sumelic Well, people do still have to acquire the pied-piping constructions _somehow_, or they couldn't use them, or grammatically judge them. And I suspect that even happens during primary language acquisition; I don't think (at least older) children are baffled when they hear a butler talking on TV—they may find it silly, but they understand it. So I think it's still "naturally acquired grammar". But otherwise, I think you're probably on the money here.

Comment: Very interesting discussion. I'm fascinated by relative infinitives, and how they segue into reduced question infinitives. Normally relative infinitives don't allow _Wh_-words: *_the man who to talk to_ vs _the man to talk to_, unless they're pied-piped, when they become required: _the man to whom to talk_ vs *_the man to to talk_. Not surprising, really -- the _Wh_-word is the head of the phrase and without it there's no purpose for the fronted prep. It really puzzles me how we figure out whether Su or DO is being relativized: _the man to see/the man to do the job_.

Comment: @jlawler The second one is easy: Subj is the only empty argument slot (staying neutral about gaps vs. PRO vs. whatever), so the man must fill in the Subj. The first one has two slots, so one has to be filled by the man, and the other is a free variable to be filled in by a larger context, so your theory needs a rule that says the local filler prefers the DO to the Subj. Different theories do that in different ways, but if you ignore the difference between movement, syntactic linking, and semantic linking they all end up stipulating equivalent rules.

Comment: @jlawler Meanwhile, as I get into the Culicover book I mentioned, he's got a great discussion of relative clauses, non-clausal relatives, and all the related things (e.g., free relatives). His treatment of both the syntax (if you like CxG approaches) and the semantics seems pretty compelling.

Comment: Btw, the same pattern you describe in your penultimate comment also holds for the *too ADJ to verb* construction: *too big to fail* (describes implied subject of *fail*) vs. *too fast to catch* (describes implied object of *catch*).

Comment: Yeah, there's a lot of places where infinitives can niche in idioms. And hierarchies of rules to employ if one fails, like _stop smoking_ vs _stop to smoke_, where the infinitive has to be interpreted as a purpose clause instead of a complement.

Comment: @TKR Isn't that one is even more straightforward—it doesn't even matter what the specific thematic or grammatical roles are, it's just transitive vs. intransitive? Without a few more examples, I'm not sure.

Comment: @TKR Actually, consider "optionally transitive" verbs (however you choose to analyze that). There's probably a better example, but the first one that comes to mind is "John is too drunk to fuck". That's ambiguous: it can mean John being too drunk to fuck (anyone), or John being too drunk for me to (ethically) fuck him.

Comment: "to who" does not work...

Comment: @LukeSawczak In what context? Surely [Cindy McCain may hold key to who gets husband's Senate seat](https://www.cnn.com/2018/12/16/politics/ip-forecast/index.html) is correct, given that "who" is a subject there. And even in many contexts where "who" is in an object position, most native English speakers habitually use "to who", not "to whom", so, unless you think everyone who speaks English is wrong about English (in which case you're not doing linguistics), "to who" certainly does work.

Comment: @abarnert Sorry, I should have been more specific. That example is good, but I think "To who were you talking" would be marked (at best) for most speakers. Two possible factors: (1) Speakers normally move the prep. to the end, "to who" feeling like a formal variant and thus jarring with "who": the set of people who front the prep. and the set of people who use "whom" after a prep. mostly overlap. (2) Because of the relative rarity of fronted prep., clichés like "To whom it may concern" and "For whom the bell tolls" dominate. (Would be interesting to test intuitions about other prepositions.)

Comment: @abarnert ...In fact, in the example you gave in your comment, which is very structurally different from the one in the question, "whom" would not be licensed. P.S. Certainly descriptivism guides our work here — which is why I should further clarify that "to who" is only likely to be rejected before the verb, but likely to be accepted after the verb, as in your 8th sentence, in line with my previous comment about fronting — but it's worth noting the caveat that speaker intuitions are hard to speak definitively about when it's a structure many speakers don't acquire (consistent) use of.

Comment: @LukeSawczak So the points you're making are the ones I make in my answer: there's a correlation between pied-piped constructions and preferring or requiring "whom", and pied-piped constructions are used almost exclusively in formal register (and, presumably, those facts are somehow connected), right? The cliches are an interesting added point, though.

Comment: I question the grammaticality of "I already told you about the man to whom to talk."

Comment: @GregLee I took that one out of a paper… although unfortunately I didn't keep notes, so I don't remember _which_ paper. (I think it was by Adele Goldberg, but I wouldn't bet much on that.) There's clearly a processing-complexity issue there, and I don't want to just dismiss it as "that's just competence-vs.-performance, and performance doesn't matter" a la Chomsky, but I suspect it is within performance bounds for most native speakers, not just whichever author I borrowed it from. Maybe it deserves a ?, but not a *. And it's _definitely_ substantially worse with "to who".

Comment: @abarnert It does sound from that summary like we're on the same page re: pied-piped  ~ formal & pied-piped ~ "whom". (Not sure why it's not worth fixing or marking that example in your corpus example above, though, since it seems like an egregious one to me!)

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by sumelic in the comments, my corpus is woefully incomplete, and I missed the important generalization. The preposition doesn't matter: "I already told you about the man to/with/about *who/whom to talk." The only reason all the examples I found used "to" is that most of the examples of pied-piped who/whom happen to use "to". So, obviously, my wild guess about phonotactics is completely wrong. Most other variables, like which position you extract from, don't matter either. The main thing that matters is pied-piping, but it's not quite that simple.

If you go through the catalog in Ivan Sag's 1997 [English Relative Clause Constructions](http://lingo.stanford.edu/sag/papers/rel-pap.pdf),<sup>1</sup> trying to cram a who/whom into every possible (non-subject) position:

- The constructions (actually construction/site pairs, not separate constructions, at least in Sag's terms) that require focus stress (although Sag doesn't get into that) prefer who, and the in-situ one requires it.
- One other (seemingly arbitrary) construction at least slightly prefers who.
- The constructions that pied-pipe prefer whom, and the infinitival one requires it.
- Everything else accepts either.

This strongly implicates register, as sumelic suggested. "You gave it to WHO?!" is the kind of thing people say in the schoolyard, and "I already told you about the man to *who/whom to talk" is the kind of thing people say in court.

But pragmatics would only explain the generalizations, not the idiosyncrasies. Plus, even if you imagine a lawyer using the in-situ stressed question in court, she still can't say "whom" without it sounding weird. So, the pragmatic register distinction has been grammaticalized—some feature of each construction is involved in the pronoun choice.

This makes perfect sense from a Construction Grammar view of synchronic language (good but not perfect generalization from "syntactic nuts") and a Goldbergian view of language evolution (pragmatics, and the drive to generalize, cause "whom" to die out faster in some constructions than others in a way that's pretty predictable, but not perfectly so). Especially considering Luke Sawczak's point about cliches in comments—e.g., most learners have probably heard the fixed "to whom it may concern" far more than any other phrase in the same construction. I don't know how to fit it into the Chomskyan MP paradigm (even though I think Chomsky originally invented the "grammaticalized pragmatic" idea…), but that's fine.

---

<sub>1. If you're interested in the actual construction hierarchy and the explanation for it, not just the catalog, skimming Peter Culicover's 2013 book [Grammar and Complexity](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/grammar-and-complexity-9780199654604?cc=us&lang=en&), he seems to improve on Sag. I suspect Thomas Hoffman's 2011 book [Preposition Placement in English](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/preposition-placement-in-english/B581AA139DAACC450F5E6F623C4A7978) improves it in different ways—including explicitly taking register (and dialect) into account—but I haven't got a copy. On the other hand, Sag is a relatively short paper available as a free preprint, as opposed to a whole book.</sub>